# What can the proceeds from the sale of a pasul Sefer Torah be used for?

Tags: money, sefer-torah

What are the restrictions, if any, on what the proceeds on the sale of a pasul Sefer Torah can be used for?

Can the proceeds be used for capital improvements to the Shul?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86451/what-can-a-shul-do-with-unusable-torah-scrolls

Comment: Also related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29967/501

Comment: Who would want to buy a pasul Sefer Torah?