# Where to keep a non-kosher Torah scroll?

Tags: halacha, sefer-torah, invalid-pasul

*This is a follow up question to [How to find the date of my ancestors' Torah Scroll?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139719/how-to-find-the-date-of-my-ancestors-torah-scroll.)*

I am currently investigating where it could be kept in Israel while finding someone to renovate it.

One of my friends send me a reference to [Ketubot 19b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.19b.4-5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) (see below) and to the [Shulchan Arukh](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.279.2?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en).

> אִתְּמַר: סֵפֶר שֶׁאֵינוֹ מוּגָּהּ, אָמַר רַבִּי אַמֵּי: עַד שְׁלֹשִׁים יוֹם מוּתָּר לְשַׁהוֹתוֹ, מִכָּאן וְאֵילָךְ אָסוּר לְשַׁהוֹתוֹ, מִשּׁוּם שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״אַל תַּשְׁכֵּן בְּאֹהָלֶיךָ עַוְלָה״.

> On a similar note it is stated, with regard to keeping items with potential to lead to transgression: With regard to a Torah scroll that is not proofread and therefore contains errors, Rabbi Ami says: It is permitted to keep it without emending the mistakes for up to thirty days, and from that time onward it is prohibited to keep it, as it is stated: “And let not injustice dwell in your tents” (Job 11:14).

How do other synagogues deal with the issue?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29967/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/86451/759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R Moishe Dovid Lebovits adresses your question [here](https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol18Issue3.pdf)

> The Gemara says one is not allowed to keep a sefer Torah that was not
> checked (for mistakes) in one’s possession for more than thirty days.
> This is brought down in halachah as well. [...]
>
> [Reasons given are so that one doesn't read or learn halachot from
> it.]
>
> **Today, many shuls have non-kosher sifrei Torah. Isn’t this contrary to
> what it says in the Gemara and halachah?** Some suggest that there is no
> issue today since we have many sifrei Torah. If one is non-kosher we
> will not come to learn from it. In addition, today when the baal korei
> reads from the Torah everyone else follows along with a Chumash, and
> if he makes a mistake he will be corrected. Furthermore, we don’t
> learn any halachos from a sefer Torah since we learn from printed
> sefarim.

He then provides the solution

> **The practice today is to place a gartel around [the outside of] a sefer Torah that
> needs to be fixed or is passul. This reminds us not to learn from it,
> and therefore there is no issue with keeping it around for more than
> thirty days.**

and quotes the following sources: Rivevos Ephraim 2:page 97:94, Daas Kohen, Y.D. 174, Zecher Simchah 144, V’atah Kisvu, Y.D. 279:5

Beyond the *gartel*, I have also seen synagogues who place these *sifrei Torah* in plastic bags to make it clear they shouldn't be used.

Comment: This is all referring to invalid Torahs that there is some reason to keep around, but we want to be careful about the injunction against keeping mistaken books. If there's no reason to keep the Torah around and it's permanently invalid, just bury it.

Comment: Glad there might be a way to preserve it for family history. But Double AA's comment is important. The kosher Torah's will wear out by use. It's the non-kosher Torahs that will be found a thousand years from now because they were unused, well-preserved and stored away safely.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't disagree with you in general but note this OP explicitly wrote he is looking for someone to renovate the sefer Torah

Comment: @PaulWalker your comment and DoubleAA's comment disagree, burying a sefer Torah is not a way to store it away safely

Comment: I'd be hesitant to put it into a plastic bag... moisture may then get trapped and create an environment in which mold may grow.

Comment: @mbloch I guess I wasn't clear. I meant that I can understand a family's sentiment to desire to keep such an important part of their history, even though it may be a non-kosher Torah. It would be put away somewhere for safekeeping, not used, rarely taken out. In other words, preserved. The Dead Sea scrolls come to mind. I was simply agreeing with DoubleAA that "if it's permanently invalid, just bury it."

Answer (score 0):

In our shul under the Aaron Hakodesh is a smaller safe where we keep the Nevi'im Haftarah scrolls on the bottom shelf.

It's not tall, so we store an old non-Kosher Sefer Torah laying down on the top shelf. It's only used on Simchat Torah for dancing.

Comment: This is potentially a problematic setup, since a box/cover/etc. for a torah cannot be used for neviim (הורדה בקדושה)